# Django Querying database based on the user input

Tags: python, django, django-views

I just started learning python/django and I'm working on a small project. I have models and an html form build. How can I query my database and filter all the names of the drivers that matches the destination city the user entered.

My models

```
class Drivers(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True, blank=False)
    destination_one = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=False)
```

My HTML form

```
<form id="searchform"  method="get" action="" accept-charset="utf-8">
  Search destination:
  <input id="searchbox" name="search_res" type="text" placeholder="Search">
  <input type="submit" value="OK">
</form>

    {% for dr in results %}

        {{dr.first_name}}
        {{dr.last_name}}
        {{dr.destination_one}}
        <br>

    {% endfor %}

    <br>
```

My View

```
def newpage(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search_res')
    if request.method == 'GET':
        results = Drivers.objects.filter(destination_one=query)
        context = RequestContext(request)
    return render_to_response(request,'busapp/newpage.html',{'results': results})
```

Models and HTML are fine. I'm having trouble building a simple def in views.py.

Comment: What exactly isn't working?

Comment: if  querry=None that will create issue in filter when user open that page without `search_res` parameter

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
def newpage(request):
    query = request.GET.get('search_res', None)
    context = {}

    if query and request.method == 'GET':
        results = Drivers.objects.filter(destination_one=query)
        context.update({'results': results})
return render(request,'busapp/newpage.html',context)
```